# KnockoutJS foreach relative to Google Maps Markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

So a bit of a weird question here. I've got a thing built in KnockoutJS, jQuery, and Google Maps. I've got a `ko.observableArray()` that I'm using for my markers.

```
viewModel.markers = ko.observableArray([
{ title: 'spot A', lat: 45.913750, lng: -89.257755, placeID: 'ChIJ9SwINsw3VE0RTDLel7J7Z-U', content: 'agh.' },
{ title: 'spot B', lat: 45.915717, lng: -89.240019, placeID: 'ChIJ-ZZXnek3VE0RBbpY67WJV1Y', content: 'This problem makes me want to scratch my eyes out.' },
{ title: 'spot C', lat: 45.934099, lng: -89.261834, placeID: 'ChIJdSZITVA2VE0RDqqRxn-Kjgw', content: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor.' }
]);
```

I've also got a front-end facing `foreach` `ul` that populates out information based on the search results being pulled from this array, specifically:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: searchResults" class="locationListMain">
  <ul class="locationList">
    <h3 class="resultTITLE"> <span data-bind="text: title"></span></h3>
    <p class="resultLATLONG">LAT <span data-bind="text: lat"></span>, LONG <span data-bind="text: lng"></span></p>
    <p class="resultCONTACT"></p>
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right resultOPEN"></span>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

What I'd like to do, however, is figure out how to make one of these `.locationList` `ul` reference to a particular google maps marker. As in, If I search for 'Spot A', then I'll return 'Spot A' in the list. If I click on 'Spot A', it'll move to and open up the `google.maps.InfoWindow();` relative to that piece of information.

Is there some way I can tie the indices of the map markers and the returned data together so I can reference one to the other when need be? I'm not 100% sure how the indices are managed when I'm making the markers, and I haven't been able to find any information that points me towards something I can work with in the google documentation + KO docs.

Just as a reference, this is my markers code, called after the map has initialized.

```
function initData(map, markers){
var markerData = markers;
for (i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++){
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markerData[i].lat, markerData[i].lng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: position,
    title: markerData[i].title
  });
  var content = markerData[i].content;
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infoWindow){
    return function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(content);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    };
  })(marker, content, infoWindow));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could inject a callback to your `initData` method that'll accept a reference/id to your `ul` element, which would have a data-tag with the same reference/id ; when you call the callback from within Maps (providing the reference/id as an argument), it'll trigger something in the `ul` tags, when you do the opposite, it'll trigger a search in your markers collection and move the map center there ; by separating your `initData` method in two, you'd be able to directly access the markers too and allow you to open it? If that makes sense.

Comment: Or use an indirection and make another object/interface that is injected in both the Map logic and the `ul` logic...

Comment: Is `searchResults` a computed? If so, it can include any tie-in you need. If not, you can make a `computed` that does.

Comment: Still working on this? Could you show what your searchResults looks like?